# Regex JavaScript : Need to match numbers in the format A12.12.122 , C1.20.23

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z]\d+\\.?\d+?\\.?\d+$/g
```

I have written this pattern but it doesn't match a single character followed by a single or two digits. It matches only when there 3 or more digits followed by a digit.
Tried groups but still didn't work

```
/^[a-zA-Z]\d+(\\.?\d+?(\\.?\d+))$/g
```

Is there a better way to write this pattern?

It should match all the alphanumeric characters for example A12, A12.25, F12.23.36, G45.36, H475. Please can anyone help with this.

Comment: You do know that two backslashes in a row designates a backslash, so most likely your regexp will not work at all for anything. You need to escape the backslash only when writing it as a string to pass to the RegExp constructor. The construct `\\.` will match one backslash followed by any character, which is not what you want.

Comment: So you are trying to get any letter number combination? What do you need this for and what are you restricting?

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah I know but when I was writing the question, it was not showing in the preview, so thought I need to include backslash.

Comment: You still have two backslashes in a row, which represent a single backslash, so your RegExp will only match things like `A222\$22\#44`.

Comment: @andre Yeah like A12, g1 etc only one character followed by numbers. I need this for input field to restrict user entering any other number apart from this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
^[a-zA-Z]\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

- `^` matches start of the line
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches any letters from a to z, in any case
- `\d+` matches any digit one or more time
- `(\.\d+)*` matches a `.` followed by one or more digits, zero or more times, at the end of the line (`$`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ5dH8/3)

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response! I can't up vote your answer because need to have 15 Reputation points. Can you please explain the pattern and what the capturing group does?

Comment: @heemayal Thank you. I want to learn regex (especially capturing groups advanced topics) so can you suggest articles or books, done a course on codeschool but it is basic.

Comment: @Nishant Ummmm...you can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match the examples that you provided and prevent incidental matches with

```
/\b[A-Z]\d+(\.\d+)*\b/i
```

The \b metacharacter prevents matching in the middle of another identifier.  The \d metacharacter matches any digit, the multiple digit sequences is handled with an optional repetition.  The /i at the end allows matching of uppercase and lowercase, without having to specify all of them in the character class.

This sample Ruby program tests the regex with the known examples, as well as some ill-formed examples.

```
data = [
  [ "A12",        true ],
  [ "A12.25",     true ],
  [ "F12.23.36",  true ],
  [ "G45.36",     true ],
  [ "H475",       true ],
  [ "A12.12.122", true ],
  [ "C1.20.23",   true ],
  [ "C.4",        false ],
  [ "BB9",        false ],
  [ "123",        false ],
  [ "1.F",        false ],
  [ "8CF",        false ],
  [ "D3D",        false ]
]

data.each do |pair|
  puts "#{pair[1] == !(pair[0] =~ /\b[A-Z]\d+(\.\d+)*\b/i).nil? ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{pair[0]}'"
end
```

After running this program, it displays the following output:

```
> ruby regex-test.rb
Pass: 'A12'
Pass: 'A12.25'
Pass: 'F12.23.36'
Pass: 'G45.36'
Pass: 'H475'
Pass: 'A12.12.122'
Pass: 'C1.20.23'
Pass: 'C.4'
Pass: 'BB9'
Pass: '123'
Pass: '1.F'
Pass: '8CF'
Pass: 'D3D'
```

Note that 'Pass' in this case means that the regex either finds the expression, or fails as expected.  The second element in each pair in the `data` array determines if the regex should match or not, and when it should not, a 'Pass' will occur if it is not matched as expected.

Comment: You ultimately need to be careful using Ruby to test regular expressions for Javascript. For instance, Javascript regular expressions do not support recursion or look-behinds. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

Comment: Thank you Michael! I can't up vote your answer as 15 reputation needed.